# define a specialization for a single member of a class template

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

I have a template class (or is it a class template?) with many member functions. I have definitions for all of them. I would like to override one of the definitions, for a particular value of T. I am hoping that I don't have to provide definitions for all of the member functions for this particular value of T since they'll all be identical to the definitions for generic T.

I've tried something like below, but I get a linker error " ... one or more multiply defined symbols found"

Am I using the wrong syntax or am I doing something that is simply not allowed in C++.

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    void a(T);
    void b(T);
    ...
    void z(T);
};

void A<int>::a(int)
{
    // do something special for this particular template parameter
}

template <typename T>
void A<T>::a(T){}

template <typename T>
void A<T>::b(T){}

...

template <typename T>
void A<T>::z(T){}
```

Just to be concrete, here is some real code that causes the same problem:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{ 
    void f(T);
};

template<> // same linker error with or without this line
void A<int>::f(int)
{
    // something special
}

template<typename T>
void A<T>::f(T)
{
}
```

Comment: "Class template" is the appropriate terminology :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That question deals with explicit *instantiations*, not explicit *specializations*.

Comment: I don't really understand the difference between those two terms. I suspect that's part of the reason that I can't get this to work. Is there an easy fix? (my recent edit to the original post shows that simply adding the line template<> has no effect).

Comment: I posted an answer showcasing a workaround, but technically you can't just specialize individual class methods. (You have to specialize the class, ergo re-implementing all of its methods)

Comment: In the most recent edit of the post, I included failed code where all (i.e. one) class methods of the specialized class are implemented and it still causes an error.

Comment: An explicit instantiation is where you tell the compiler to instantiate a particular template. The compiler will then generate the code necessary for that particular template, as if you had called the function (for function templates) or all the non-template member functions (for class templates). An explicit *specialization* is where you tell the compiler that for a particular set of template arguments, you have a different definition than the default. The latter is applicable in your post, as you want to do something different for `A<int>::f(int)` than the regular `A<T>::f(T)`

Comment: @JosephFranciscus "but technically you can't just specialize individual class methods" [Yes, you can](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#15).

Answer (score 4):

You're almost correct, you're just missing `template<>` to indicate an explicit specialization:

```
template<>
void A<int>::a(int)
{
}
```

**Edit**: The answer below correctly points out that if you want to have this implementation in a header, you should use the `inline` specifier. Alternatively, you could opt to move the implementation to the source file, 
in which case you should still *declare* the explicit specialization in the header file. In other words, it adheres to regular function definition rules.

Comment: Oh hey, are we just the dedicated meta-template people on SO?

Comment: @JosephFranciscus That's what I find most interesting anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

`template<> void A<int>::f(int)` is no longer a template. So non longer `inline`.

You have to implement it in cpp (and declare it in header)

or add `inline` to avoid to have multiple definition (so definition in header).

```
template<> inline void A<int>::f(int)
{
    // something special
}
```

Comment: Just to nitpick on terminology somwehat, his template versions were also not inline. The standard mentions member functions with a body within the class definition as implicitely inline, but it does not to so for function templates. Rather, it states that a function template can have more than one definition, as long as each definition is in a different translation unit and is "the same" (not going to list all the requirements but you get the point).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the responders above. My issue was essentially that I was missing the keyword inline. Here is what works (paraphrased)

```
 // in header file:

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    void a(T);
    void b(T);
    ...
    void z(T);
};

template <typename T>
void A<T>::a(T){}

template <typename T>
void A<T>::b(T){}

...

template <typename T>
void A<T>::z(T){}

// in .cpp file:
template <typename T>
inline void A<int>::a(int)
{
    // do something special for this particular template parameter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am hoping that I don't have to provide definitions for all of the member functions for this particular value of T since they'll all be identical to the definitions for generic T.

If you can use C++11, a possible solution is SFINAE enable/disable a generic or a `int` specific `a()` version.

Something like

```
template <typename T>
struct A
 {
   template <typename U = T>
   typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_same<int, U>{}>::type a(T)
    { std::cout << "generic version" << std::endl; }

   template <typename U = T>
   typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_same<int, U>{}>::type a(T)
    { std::cout << "integer version" << std::endl; }

   void b(T) {}
   void z(T) {}
 };
```

To avoid that the `a()` method can be used in this way

```
A<float>{}.a<int>();
```

The test for `std::enable_if` can be modified to check that `T` and `U` are the same type

```
   template <typename U = T>
   typename std::enable_if<(false == std::is_same<int, U>{})
                        && (true == std::is_same<T, U>{})>::type a(T)
    { std::cout << "generic version" << std::endl; }

   template <typename U = T>
   typename std::enable_if<(true == std::is_same<int, U>{})
                        && (true == std::is_same<T, U>{})>::type a(T)
    { std::cout << "integer version" << std::endl; }
```

If you need a C++98 solution, you can simulate `std::is_same` and `std::enable_if` as follows

```
template <typename, typename>
struct isSame
 { static const bool value = false; };

template <typename T>
struct isSame<T, T>
 { static const bool value = true; };

template <bool, typename>
struct enableIf
 { };

template <typename T>
struct enableIf<true, T>
 { typedef T type; };
```

and your `A` `struct` can be written

```
template <typename T>
struct A
 {
   template <typename U>
   typename enableIf<(false == isSame<int, U>::value)
                  && (true == isSame<T, U>::value), void>::type a(U)
    { std::cout << "generic version" << std::endl; }

   template <typename U>
   typename enableIf<(true == isSame<int, U>::value)
                  && (true == isSame<T, U>::value), void>::type a(U)
    { std::cout << "integer version" << std::endl; }

   void b(T) {}
   void z(T) {}
 };
```

Another possible C++11 solution, that doen't use SFINAE but a couple of helper methods, is a "tag dispatching" one

```
template <typename T>
struct A
 {
   void a_helper (T, std::true_type const &)
    { std::cout << "integer version" << std::endl; }

   void a_helper (T, std::false_type const &)
    { std::cout << "generic version" << std::endl; }

   void a (T t)
    { a_helper(t, std::is_same<T, int>{}); }

   void b(T) {}
   void z(T) {}
 };
```

Comment: I don't mean to be unappreciative, but that suggestion seems rather sophisticated. Isn't this a common situation (with a standard solution) ?

Comment: @sitiposit - as far I know, yes: starting from C++11 is almost common; a tipical C++11 + SFINAE solution. The first time I've seen something similar I find it to much sophisticated but, with time and use, I find it very natural. Give me some time and I add a C++98 simulation of this solution and a C++11 solution non SFINAE based and (IMHO) a little simpler.

Comment: @sitiposit - answer modified with a C++98 version of the SFINAE solution and a different C++11 "tag dispatching" (non SFINAE) solution.

Comment: I don't see why you need such an elaborate SFINAE approach if the goal is just to explicitely specialize a single member function.